# Clone or copy an image keeping the same size

Tags: vb.net, image, copy, size, clone

I would like to clone (or copy?) an image.

Here is the context:

I click on a button which open a OpenFileDialog. I pick an image (Jpeg, Size 4MB) and display it in a Picturebox.

Then I would like in the same event (clicked button) save a copy of this image in a specified folder (Keeping the format Jpeg and the Size 4MB).

My question is which method should I use? So far, I can get a Jpeg copy, but the size is different. And I am not really sure what to do.

Any help or a link or a direction will be appreciated.

Thank you.

JLuc01

Comment: If it starts as a file you dont need to do anything with the image, just copy the file.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just for information, after being directed to the right direction, here is the code I used:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(myOpenFileDialog.FileName, 
          myPath + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(myOpenFileDialog.FileName))
```

It was actually easy.